how to create correlation matrix plot that shows correlation coefficients only between variables in r
I am trying to use this code corPlot(selected_data,tl.cex = 0.66) to create a correlation matrix plot that shows correlation coefficients only in a plot form. When I run the code, this error keeps on popping up, Error in corrplot(corr_matrix, tl.cex = tl.cex) : unused argument (tl.cex = tl.cex). Here is the code:
selected_data <- clean_odata45 %>%
dplyr::select(funded_amnt, inq_last_6mths, open_il_6m, open_il_12m, open_il_24m, total_bal_il, all_util, inq_fi, inq_last_12m, num_il_tl, total_il_high_credit_limit, int_rate, annual_inc, revol_util)
names(selected_data)
#correlation plot with calculated correlation coefficients
corPlot(selected_data,tl.cex = 0.66)
I tried installing dplyr package, removing the argument tl.cex = 0.66 but the error still exists
